# Debugging the template code in header file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have made some changes in the templatized function ( obviously defined in header file ) :-

```
template<T>
void foo()
{
}
```

which is present in library xyz.dll. Now when I make any changes in this function I have to do [b -f "compile libs" xyz].

But still after forcing the build, I am not able to debug the code in that header file properly as source file seems to be different from object file from the perspective of debugger.

Could anyone please help me know what I am doing wrong over here.

Comment: Did you try to cleanup and rebuild everything?

Comment: No, but what effect would it produce and my code base is huge. That means it would an hour to say the least.